# Double-clicking button to render another component using conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `react-router-dom` to link two pages by pressing buttons.

If I add conditional rendering to `Link`, it requires double click to render the second page.

Here is the `Page_1` component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Page_1 = () => {
  const [allow, setAllow] = React.useState(false);

  const allowPermission = () => {
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    arr.length > 2 && setAllow(true);
  };

  return (
    <Link to={allow && "/page_2"}>
      <button onClick={() => allowPermission()}>To page_2</button>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default Page_1;
```

I have already tried using `useEffect()` and `useState()`'s callback function, but couldn't achieve that. Here is also the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-paper-l0nnbt?file=/src/pages/Page_1.jsx).

Answer (score -1):

The first time the component is rendered, the Link is set with no path, as `allow` is still `false`.

When you click the button for the first time: (i) Link will still have no path, and so it won't navigate to page 2; and then (ii) `allow` will be set to `true`, which will trigger a rerender, and therefore set Link path to `"/page_2"`.

The second click will get the correct path, after the rerender.

One way to fix this is with `useEffect` with an empty dependency array, which will call `setAllow` once when the component renders and therefore trigger a rerender:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Page_1 = () => {
  const [allow, setAllow] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    arr.length > 2 && setAllow(true);
  }, [])

  return (
    <Link to={allow && "/page_2"}>
      <button>To page_2</button>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default Page_1;
```

If the condition to set `allow` changes, you can trigger a rerender every time `allow` changes by adding it to the dependency array:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Page_1 = () => {
  const [allow, setAllow] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    arr.length > 2 && setAllow(true);
  }, [allow])

  return (
    <Link to={allow && "/page_2"}>
      <button>To page_2</button>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default Page_1;
```

Comment: The state should be updated when button is pressed.

Comment: That's the behavior you already have, but it doesn't make sense... The way you have it, the first click updates the state, the second click gets the correct path and navigates to Page_2. Now if you manage to update the state of Page_1 and redirect to Page_2 at the same time (i.e., on the first click), the state for Page_1 will be destroyed as the component will be unmounted. I don't really see what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe update your question to add more details.

Comment: I mean, just by clicking button first time, it should redirect another page or stays on same page (if `state` stays `false`)

Comment: I guess, not too hard to understand what I meant.

Comment: That's exactly what the options in my answer do. The state is being updated inside the useEffect. There's no way to do what you want by updating state on click, for the reasons I outline in the first paragraphs of my answer.